# Visual Studio 2013 NodeJS Tools, TypeScript, Keep Comments

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, typescript, edge.js

That's my setup.  VS 2013, with the Node JS Tools, and Typescript.  Adding a .ts file is handled without a hiccup.  I am having some issues with the npm integration, but I've been able to work around them.

I've also added EdgeJS.  It doesn't yet support TypeScript but I just write my EdgeJS calls with regular JS in my TS files.  The problem is that EdgeJS allos you to write your CS functions a few different ways.

One way is like the following, where the entire body is enclosed in a comment block:

```
var hello = edge.func(function () {/*
    async(input) => {
      return ".NET welcomes " + input.ToString();
    }
*/});
```

Unfortunately, the TS compiler, by default, removes these comments and I can't find a way *in this project type* to change that behavior.

Am I just out of luck (for now)?

Comment: I'm not sure what's removing the comments. I'm editing a file using the exact config you describe and comments remain when compiled to JavaScript. Do you have any grunt tasks/post build steps that might be stripping comments?

Comment: I thought the tsc default was to remove comments.  It clearly that or something associated with which is.  To answer your question, no.  What project type did you start with?

Comment: I started with the empty NodeJs typescript project.

Comment: I have pretty much the same setup, but for me it's web essentials that is eating the comments when it compiles the TS files. Since the options changed, there doesn't seen to be a way to keep all comments just "important" ones that start with a !.

Comment: @Rangoric Which version of VS?  I'm not using Web Essentials, but I just tried it again and it definitely eats multi-line comments (but not single-line).

Comment: @WiredPrairie Were you using multi-line or single-line comments?

Comment: Comments need to start on a line by their own (in order for them to be preserved), regardless of single/multi-line.

Comment: @WiredPrairie and *THAT'S* the answer.  Put it in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preserve comments for TypeScript, you'll need to start them on a new line.  In the example you provided, the multi-line comment is not preserved as it starts on the end of a line with code.

Simply move the block comment start:

```
var edge = edge.func(() => {
    /*
      async(input) => {

      }
    */
});
```

Comment: Accepting the answer because it is technically correct.  It didn't turn-out to solve my *real* problem, but it turns out I didn't ask my real question...